# Why am I getting "Error 404 not found" in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

This is my issue: When I run the command `rails server` and go to localhost:3000 I get the page "Error 404 not found", so I try to put localhost:3000/home because it is a view but the issues continue. This is the log in the CMD..

```
C:\Sites\ifurniture>rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.2.7.1 application starting in development on http://localhost:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2016-08-16 12:45:45] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2016-08-16 12:45:45] INFO  ruby 2.2.4 (2015-12-16) [i386-mingw32]
[2016-08-16 12:45:45] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=192 port=3000


Started GET "/" for ::1 at 2016-08-16 12:45:47 -0500
  ActiveRecord::SchemaMigration Load (1.0ms)  SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM
"schema_migrations"
Processing by Refinery::PagesController#home as HTML
  Parameters: {"locale"=>:es}
  Refinery::Page Load (1.0ms)  SELECT  "refinery_pages".* FROM "refinery_pages"
WHERE "refinery_pages"."link_url" = ? LIMIT 1  [["link_url", "/"]]
  Refinery::Page Load (7.0ms)  SELECT  "refinery_pages".* FROM "refinery_pages"
WHERE "refinery_pages"."menu_match" = ?  ORDER BY "refinery_pages"."id" ASC LIMI
T 1  [["menu_match", "^/404$"]]
  Rendered public/404.html (14.0ms)
Filter chain halted as :find_page rendered or redirected
Completed 404 Not Found in 1974ms (Views: 1775.1ms | ActiveRecord: 11.0ms)


Started GET "/home" for ::1 at 2016-08-16 12:46:00 -0500
Processing by Refinery::PagesController#show as HTML
  Parameters: {"path"=>"home", "locale"=>:es}
  Refinery::Page Load (29.0ms)  SELECT  "refinery_pages".* FROM "refinery_pages"
 INNER JOIN "refinery_page_translations" ON "refinery_page_translations"."refine
ry_page_id" = "refinery_pages"."id" WHERE "refinery_pages"."parent_id" IS NULL A
ND "refinery_page_translations"."locale" IN ('es', 'en') AND "refinery_page_tran
slations"."slug" = 'home'  ORDER BY "refinery_pages"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Refinery::Page Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "refinery_pages".* FROM "refinery_pages"
WHERE "refinery_pages"."menu_match" = ?  ORDER BY "refinery_pages"."id" ASC LIMI
T 1  [["menu_match", "^/404$"]]
  Rendered public/404.html (0.0ms)
Filter chain halted as :find_page rendered or redirected
Completed 404 Not Found in 1475ms (Views: 1207.8ms | ActiveRecord: 29.0ms)
[2016-08-16 12:46:07] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2016-08-16 12:46:07] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
Exiting
```

This is my routes file..

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  # This line mounts Refinery's routes at the root of your application.
  # This means, any requests to the root URL of your application will go to Refinery::PagesController#home.
  # If you would like to change where this extension is mounted, simply change the
  # configuration option `mounted_path` to something different in config/initializers/refinery/core.rb
  #
  # We ask that you don't use the :as option here, as Refinery relies on it being the default of "refinery"
  post '/suscribir' => 'subscribe#create'
  mount Refinery::Core::Engine, at: Refinery::Core.mounted_path

end
```

The pages_Controller.rb code..

```
module Refinery
  class PagesController < ::ApplicationController
    include Pages::RenderOptions
    include Productos

    before_action :find_page, :set_canonical
    before_action :error_404, :unless => :current_user_can_view_page?

    # Save whole Page after delivery
    after_action :write_cache?

    # This action is usually accessed with the root path, normally '/'
    def home
      @posts = Blog::Post.newest_first.live.includes(:comments, :categories)
      render_with_templates?
    end

    # This action can be accessed normally, or as nested pages.
    # Assuming a page named "mission" that is a child of "about",
    # you can access the pages with the following URLs:
    #
    #   GET /pages/about
    #   GET /about
    #
    #   GET /pages/mission
    #   GET /about/mission
    #
    def show
      @productos = Refinery::Productos::Producto.all
      if should_skip_to_first_child?
        redirect_to refinery.url_for(first_live_child.url) and return
      elsif page.link_url.present?
        redirect_to page.link_url and return
      elsif should_redirect_to_friendly_url?
        redirect_to refinery.url_for(page.url), :status => 301 and return
      end

      render_with_templates?
    end

  protected

    def requested_friendly_id
      if ::Refinery::Pages.scope_slug_by_parent
        # Pick out last path component, or id if present
        "#{params[:path]}/#{params[:id]}".split('/').last
      else
        # Remove leading and trailing slashes in path, but leave internal
        # ones for global slug scoping
        params[:path].to_s.gsub(%r{\A/+}, '').presence || params[:id]
      end
    end

    def should_skip_to_first_child?
      page.skip_to_first_child && first_live_child
    end

    def should_redirect_to_friendly_url?
      requested_friendly_id != page.friendly_id || (
        ::Refinery::Pages.scope_slug_by_parent &&
        params[:path].present? && params[:path].match(page.root.slug).nil?
      )
    end

    def current_user_can_view_page?
      page.live? || authorisation_manager.allow?(:plugin, "refinery_pages")
    end

    def first_live_child
      page.children.order('lft ASC').live.first
    end

    def find_page(fallback_to_404 = true)
      @page ||= case action_name
                when "home"
                  Refinery::Page.find_by(link_url: '/')
                when "show"
                  Refinery::Page.friendly.find_by_path_or_id(params[:path], params[:id])
                end
      @page || (error_404 if fallback_to_404)
    end

    alias_method :page, :find_page

    def set_canonical
      @canonical = refinery.url_for @page.canonical if @page.present?
    end

    def write_cache?
      # Don't cache the page with the site bar showing.
      if Refinery::Pages.cache_pages_full && !authorisation_manager.allow?(:read, :site_bar)
        cache_page(response.body, File.join('', 'refinery', 'cache', 'pages', request.path).to_s)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I try to deploy all to Heroku, my app crashes and I get "Application Error".... Please help me, I'm a newbie with Ruby on Rails, thanks.

Comment: Can we see your routes.rb file?

Comment: Post code for Refinery::PagesController

Comment: Yes, i edited the post, you can see there.

Comment: Added the pages controller code in the post.

Comment: Can you confirm that the "current_user_can_view_page?" method passes validation? That is one potential source of a 404 and is a before_action on all controller methods exposed to routes in that file.

Comment: Looks like you are getting redirected by the `find_page` method. What is the value of `@page` right before `@page || (error_404 if fallback_to_404)`? Log the value or use pry or something to inspect it.

Comment: No, all it's all right, i can't find the problem :c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i can resolve the issue just running the CMD

```
bundle exec rake db:seed
```

thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

@iFurniture, problem is here, your 'fallback_to_404' is set to true, 
so you get always error_404

```
def find_page(fallback_to_404 = true)
  @page ||= ...
  @page || (error_404 if fallback_to_404)
end
```

I suggest you do it like this:

```
def find_page(fallback_to_404: false)
  error_404 if fallback_to_404
  @page ||= ...
  @page || (error_404 if fallback_to_404)
end
```

So fallback_to_404 will be false by default and if you want to set it true, just call it like that

```
find_page(fallback_to_404: true)
```

[Ruby 2 Keyword Arguments](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/ruby-2-keyword-arguments)

About this:

```
@page || (error_404 if fallback_to_404)
```

May be you want ?

```
fallback_to_404 ? error_404 : @page
```

Look a litle better.

Comment: That change the web, but now i got this problem..

``undefined method `live?' for nil:NilClass

Rails.root: C:/Sites/ifurniture
Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/refinery/pages_controller.rb:66:in `current_user_can_view_page?'``

Comment: Depends what is going on when page is nil? And what logic is in `current_user_can_vi‌‌​​ew_page?` method.  If you want just safely pass this condition do it like that `page && page.live? || ...`

Comment: When the page is nil i want to go to 404 not found, but "home" is not nil and continue give me 404 not found.

Answer (score 0):

I would check your `before_action :error_404, :unless => :current_user_can_view_page?` Maybe remove that code for the time being to see if it can load up, if it does then there is a good chance that the method is set up incorrectly.

Comment: Hi, don't work removing the code, i got the same issue :c